# Create PDF of dynamic size with typography using UIView template(s)

Tags: swift, pdf, uiview, logic

I'm new but have managed to learn a lot and create a pretty awesome (I hope) app that's near completion. One of my last tasks is to create a PDF of dynamically generated user data. It has been the most frustrating part of this whole process as there is no real modern clear cut template or guide. Apple's documentation isn't very descriptive (and some parts I don't understand) and the Q/A here on stack and examples on Google all seem very case specific. I thought I almost had it by using a UIScrollView but the end result was messy and I couldn't get things to line up neat enough, nor did I have enough control.

I believe my flaws with this task are logic related and not knowing enough about available APIs, help on either is greatly appreciated.

I have dynamically created user content filling an NSArray in a subclass of a UIViewController. That content consists of Strings and Images.

I would like to use a UIView (I'm presuming in a .xib file) to create a template with header information for the first page of the PDF (the header information is dynamic as well), any page after that can be done via code as it really is just a list.

I have a small understanding of UIGraphicsPDF... and would like to draw the text and images into the PDF and not just take a screen shot of the view.

My trouble with getting this going is: 
(I'm being basic here on purpose because what I have done so far has led me nowhere)

How do I find out how many pages I'm going to need?

How do I find out if text is longer than a page and how do I split it?

How do I draw images in the PDF?

How do I draw text in the PDF?

How do I draw both text and images in the PDF but padded vertically so there's no overlap and account for Strings with a dynamic number of lines?

How do I keep track of the pages?

Thank you for reading, I hoe the cringe factor wasn't too high.

Comment: Just calling print on a view produces lousy results. You need to do that yourself if you want reliable output. Apple has quite some docu on how to create PDF: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html

Comment: Yeah I've seen those docs quite often in my search but they don't tell me how to draw the PDF with a bunch of dynamic data, nor how to 'make it look pretty'.

Comment: Because it's difficult. It took me a couple of days to work through it and then a couple more days to make my output pretty. There is no simple solution :-(

Comment: How did you figure out the number of pages? Did you iterate through your content and create a height from it and then divide it by page height? That's what I'm thinking to do. I'm also thinking to create UIview with a page full of data and send that to a function to draw the page but am having a hard time keeping track of it all.

Comment: Also I babe no idea now to iterate through the UIView to have its items data drawn natively into the PDF.

Comment: I found an (Obj-C) example somewhere that did setup a View and a print controller which knows (calculates) the pages. Then the print view is called to generate the view which is then sent to PDF. Unfortunately as said the matter is complicated and I can not answer it here. Maybe I can summarize it as an answer. Cant promise though.

Answer (score 4):

So here we go. The following was made for OSX with NSView but it's easily adapatable for UIView (so I guess). You will need the following scaffold:

A) PSPrintView will handle a single page to print

```
class PSPrintView:NSView {
  var pageNo:Int = 0 // the current page
  var totalPages:Int = 0
  struct PaperDimensions {
    size:NSSize // needs to be initialized from NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo
    var leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin : CGFloat
  }
  let paperDimensions = PaperDimensions(...)

  class func clone() -> PSPrintView {
    // returns a clone of self where most page parameters are copied
    // to speed up printing
  }

  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    // Drawing code here.

    // e.g. to draw a frame inside the view
    let scale = convertSize(NSMakeSize(1, 1), fromView:nil)
    var myContext = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()!.CGContext
    CGContextSetLineWidth(myContext, scale.height)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(myContext, NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect (myContext, rect)
    rect.origin.x += paperDimensions.leftMargin
    rect.origin.y += paperDimensions.bottomMargin
    rect.size.width -= paperDimensions.leftMargin + paperDimensions.rightMargin
    rect.size.height -= paperDimensions.topMargin + paperDimensions.bottomMargin
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myContext, NSColor(red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor)
    CGContextStrokeRect(myContext, rect)

    // here goes your layout with lots of String.drawInRect....
  }
}
```

B) PSPrint: will hold the single PSPrintViews in an array and when done send them to the (PDF) printer

```
class PSPrint: NSView {
  var printViews = [PSPrintView]()

  override func knowsPageRange(range:NSRangePointer) -> Bool {
    range.memory.location = 1
    range.memory.length = printViews.count
    return true
  }

  func printTheViews() {
    let sharedPrintInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo()
    let numOfViews = printViews.count

    var totalHeight:CGFloat = 0;//if not initialized to 0 weird problems occur after '3' clicks to print
    var heightOfView:CGFloat = 0
    //    PSPrintView *tempView;

    for tempView in printViews {
      heightOfView = tempView.frame.size.height
      totalHeight = totalHeight + heightOfView
    }
    //Change the frame size to reflect the amount of pages.
    var newsize = NSSize()
    newsize.width = sharedPrintInfo.paperSize.width-sharedPrintInfo.leftMargin-sharedPrintInfo.rightMargin
    newsize.height = totalHeight
    setFrameSize(newsize)
    var incrementor = -1 //default the incrementor for the loop below.  This controls what page a 'view' will appear on.

    //Add the views in reverse, because the Y position is bottom not top.  So Page 3 will have y coordinate of 0.  Doing this so order views is placed in array reflects what is printed.
    for (var i = numOfViews-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      incrementor++
      let tempView = printViews[i] //starts with the last item added to the array, in this case rectangles, and then does circle and square.
      heightOfView = tempView.frame.size.height

      tempView.setFrameOrigin(NSMakePoint(0, heightOfView*CGFloat(incrementor))) //So for the rectangle it's placed at position '0', or the very last page.

      addSubview(tempView)
    }
    NSPrintOperation(view: self, printInfo: sharedPrintInfo).runOperation()
  }
```

C) a function to perform printing (from the menu)

```
func doPrinting (sender:AnyObject) {
  //First get the shared print info object so we know page sizes.  The shared print info object acts like a global variable.
  let sharedPrintInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo()

  //initialize it's base values.
  sharedPrintInfo.leftMargin = 0
  sharedPrintInfo.rightMargin = 0
  sharedPrintInfo.topMargin = 0
  sharedPrintInfo.bottomMargin = 0

  var frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sharedPrintInfo.paperSize.width-sharedPrintInfo.leftMargin-sharedPrintInfo.rightMargin, height: sharedPrintInfo.paperSize.height-sharedPrintInfo.topMargin-sharedPrintInfo.bottomMargin)
  //Initiate the printObject without a frame, it's frame will be decided later.
  let printObject = PSPrint ()

  //Allocate a new instance of NSView into the variable printPageView
  let basePrintPageView = PSPrintView(frame: frame)
  // do additional init stuff for the single pages if needed
  // ...

  var printPageView:PSPrintView
  for pageNo in 0..<basePrintPageView.totalPages {
    printPageView = basePrintPageView.clone()  
    //Set the option for the printView for what it should draw.
    printPageView.pageNo = pageNo
    //Finally append the view to the PSPrint Object.
    printObject.printViews.append(printPageView)
  }
  printObject.printTheViews() //print all the views, each view being a 'page'.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer though, I actually ended up doing it in a pretty simple way, I'll share below.

Comment: @thefredelement actually I got it from someone else posting his Obj-C code a while ago. During RE to Swift I figured out a bit more how it actually worked (I was happy to get it running without having to understand details). Your approach looks interesting. Maybe you could share it on github once you got a generic form?

Comment: What's supposed to be in the function `clone()`, in part a? I'm trying to recreate what you made here so I can create a paginated PDF of some text in Swift for Cocoa.

Comment: Ok, so I just took `clone()` out and using your code, I'm just getting a blank PDF in the print dialog even though a changed `Frame` in `doPrinting()` to the frame of my text view. What can I do to make this create a PDF of the text in my text view? (Thanks in advance)

Comment: This won't work without the clone(). It's creating an exact copy of the passed object.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF drawing code:

```
import UIKit

class CreatePDF {

// Create a PDF from an array of UIViews
// Return a URL of a temp dir / pdf file

func getScaledImageSize(imageView: UIImageView) -> CGSize {

    var scaledWidth     = CGFloat(0)
    var scaledHeight    = CGFloat(0)

    let image = imageView.image!

    if image.size.height >= image.size.width {

        scaledHeight    = imageView.frame.size.height
        scaledWidth     = (image.size.width / image.size.height) * scaledHeight

        if scaledWidth > imageView.frame.size.width {

            let diff : CGFloat  = imageView.frame.size.width - scaledWidth
            scaledHeight        = scaledHeight + diff / scaledHeight * scaledHeight
            scaledWidth         = imageView.frame.size.width

        }

    } else {

        scaledWidth     = imageView.frame.size.width
        scaledHeight    = (image.size.height / image.size.width) * scaledWidth

        if scaledHeight > imageView.frame.size.height {

            let diff : CGFloat  = imageView.frame.size.height - scaledHeight
            scaledWidth         = scaledWidth + diff / scaledWidth * scaledWidth
            scaledHeight        = imageView.frame.size.height

        }

    }

    return CGSizeMake(scaledWidth, scaledHeight)

}

func drawImageFromUIImageView(imageView: UIImageView) {

    let theImage = imageView.image!

    // Get the image as it's scaled in the image view
    let scaledImageSize = getScaledImageSize(imageView)

    let imageFrame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, scaledImageSize.width, scaledImageSize.height)

    theImage.drawInRect(imageFrame)

}

func drawTextFromLabel(aLabel: UILabel) {

    if aLabel.text?.isEmpty == false {

        let theFont             = aLabel.font
        let theAttributedFont   = [NSFontAttributeName: theFont!]

        let theText     = aLabel.text!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()) as NSString
        let theFrame    = aLabel.frame

        theText.drawInRect(theFrame, withAttributes: theAttributedFont)

    }

}

func parseSubviews(aView: UIView) {

    for aSubview in aView.subviews {

        if aSubview.isKindOfClass(UILabel) {

            // Draw label

            drawTextFromLabel(aSubview as! UILabel)

        }

        if aSubview.isKindOfClass(UIImageView) {

            // Draw image (scaled and at correct coordinates

            drawImageFromUIImageView(aSubview as! UIImageView)
        }

    }

}

func parseViewsToRender(viewsToRender: NSArray) {

    for aView in viewsToRender as! [UIView] {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil)

        parseSubviews(aView)

    }

}

func createPdf(viewsToRender: NSArray, filename: String) -> NSURL {

    // Create filename

    let tempDir     = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    let pdfFilename = tempDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFilename, CGRectZero, nil)

    // begin to render the views in this context

    parseViewsToRender(viewsToRender)

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    return NSURL(string: pdfFilename)!

    }

}
```

First, I made a xib file with a UIView that fit the dimensions of a single PDF page and for my header information. This size is 612 points wide by 790 points tall.

Then I added UILabels for all of the page 1 header information I want to use (name, address, date, etc.)

I took note of y position and height of the lowest UILabel for my header information and subtracted it from the amount of vertical space in a page.

I also took note of the font and font size I wanted to use.

Then I created a class called CreatePDF

In that class I created several variables and constants, the font name, the font size, the size of a page, the remaining vertical space after header information.

In that class I created a method that takes two different arguments, one is a dictionary that I used for header information, the other is an array of UIImages and Strings.

That method calls a few other methods:

1. Determine the vertical height required for the items in the array

To do this I created another two methods, one to determine the height of a UILabel with any given string  and one to determine the height of an image (vertical and horizontal images having different heights the way that I scale them). They each returned a CGFloat, which I added to a variable in the method that kept track of all the items in array.

For each item that was “sized” I then added another 8 points to use as a vertical offset.

2. Determine how many pages will be needed

The above method returned a CGFloat that I then used to figure out if either all the items will fit on one page below the header or if another page will be needed, and if so, how many more pages.

3. Draw a UIView

This method accepts the above mentioned dictionary, array and an estimated number of pages. It returns an array of UIViews.

In this method I create a UIView that matches the size of one PDF Page, I run a loop for each page and add items to it, I check to see if an item will fit by comparing it’s y position and height with the reaming vertical space on a page by subtracting the current Y position from the page height then I add an item and keep track of it’s height and y position, If the remaining height won’t work and I’m out of pages, I add another page.

4. Send the array to draw a PDF

I create the PDF context here

I take the array of UIViews as an argument, for each view I create a PDF Page in the PDF Context and then iterate through it’s subviews, if it’s a UILabel I send it off to a function that draws the UILabel at it’s frame position with it’s text property as the string. I create an attributed front using the variables defined in the class earlier. If it’s an image I send it to another function that also uses it’s frame, however I have to send it to yet another function to determine the actual dimensions of the image that’s drawn inside the UIImage (it changes based on scaling) and I return that for where to draw the image (this happens above too to properly size it).

That’s pretty much it, in my case I created the PDF context with a file, then end up returning the file to whoever calls this function. The hardest part for me to wrap my head around was keeping track of the vertical positioning.

I’ll work on making the code more generic and post it up somewhere.