# Create a PDF in Swift with long text

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

My app is a diary and I'd like to allow the user to export app content into a PDF, but I don't know how to divide long text into multiple pages.

To create a page (with images, text, etc.) I've created a XIB file as template; for example the text in the PDF is generated from a UITextView that is included in the template.

Here is the code to generate text from a UITextView:

```
func drawTextFromTextView(textview: UITextView) {


    var frame: CGRect = textview.frame
    frame.size.height = textview.contentSize.height
    textview.frame = frame
    textview.sizeToFit()

    if textview.text?.isEmpty == false {

        let theFont = textview.font
        let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = textview.textAlignment
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

        let theAttributedFont: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: theFont!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]

        let theText = textview.text!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()) as NSString
        let theFrame = CGRectMake(textview.frame.origin.x, textview.frame.origin.y, textview.frame.size.width, textview.frame.size.height)

        theText.drawInRect(theFrame, withAttributes: theAttributedFont)

    }

}
```

**PDFpage** is the template UIView linked to the XIB file.
In **parseSubviews** I generate text and images in the PDF from PDFpage's subviews (UILabels, UIImageView, UITextView, etc.).

```
func parseViewsToRender(viewsToRender: [PDFpage]) {

    for aView in viewsToRender /*as! [UIView]*/ {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil)

        parseSubviews(aView)

    }

}

func create(viewsToRender: [PDFpage], filename: String) -> NSURL {

    // Create filename

    //let tempDir     = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    //let pdfFilename = tempDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    let pdfFilename = filename

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFilename, CGRectZero, nil)

    // begin to render the views in this context

    parseViewsToRender(viewsToRender)

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pdfFilename)!

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure I described it below the code in this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460700/create-pdf-of-dynamic-size-with-typography-using-uiview-templates

Comment: Have you used UILabel for long text?